# How to get a whole string value from a substring pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to get a string from a sub-string.

```
String whlval = "I have stackoverflow accounts and i use to login from different users 
                 i.e Angel23552 wow isn't it";
```

So i want to retrieve the whole value "Angel23552" i.e result as "Angel23552" from Angel

Conditions :-

1. I can only use Angel string to retrieve value from the String whlval as
    23552 is random value.
2. Above string i.e whlval has different spaces gaps between two 2 strings.

Comment: show what you did ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, maybe:

```
String[] split = StringUtils.split("I have   stackoverflow    accounts and i use to login from different   users  i.e Angel23552 wow isn't    it");
```

[StringUtils.split() method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Then in loop you may try to use StringUtils.contains(CharSequence seq, CharSequence searchSeq) - returns true or false

[StringUtils.contains() method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Thanks...StringUtils have a lot of apis which are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work for you?

```
String result = whlval.replaceAll(".*(Angel[^\\s]*).*","$1");
```

Comment: My bad... `replace` does not use regexp, `replaceAll` does.